# Modifying Insert data into table so that it is now Update Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Right now I am inserting blob files into a database. I have read up on the update syntax for mysql I can not figure out how to modify my code to update a row with the BLOB instead of inserting a new row with the BLOB. Could someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Create MySQL login values and
// set them to your login information.
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$tbl_name="members";

// Make the connect to MySQL or die
// and display an error.
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select your database
mysql_select_db ($database);


// Make sure the user actually
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

// Temporary file name stored on the server
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

// Read the file
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);


// Create the query and insert
// into our database.
$query = "INSERT INTO members ";
$query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
$results = mysql_query($query, $link);

// Print results
print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
print "No image selected/uploaded";
}

// Close our MySQL Link
mysql_close($link);



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1° You need to pass a referecence for what Data you are trying to update, like the Primary Key Id From Table.

2° Update SQL should be like it

```
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_image);
$id    = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_id);
$query = "UPDATE members SET image = '$data' WHERE id_image = $id";
$results = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am passing the $id through the URL right now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep. But I chose you as the best answer!

Comment: no problem sir! help is my work and vote up is the way to get some feedback thats really work! att.